Authjs session only available after manual refresh
I am using Authjs (the latest NextAuth) in my NextJS14 project to handle authentication. After logging in successfully, I programmatically route the client to '/', which works as expected. The session is made available to the whole application by wrapping the rootlayout in a ContextProvider. I expect the session to be available in my components, but it is undefined, unless I do a manual refresh.
Why is this?
//ContextWrapper.tsx
  "use client";

import {
  useContext,
  createContext,
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useTransition,
} from "react";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { publicRoutes } from "@/routes";

interface ProvidersProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const RootContext = createContext(null);

export const ContextWrapper = ({ children }: ProvidersProps) => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const user = session?.user;
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  const sessionInfo = {
    session: session,
    user: user,
    isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
    setIsLoggedIn: setIsLoggedIn,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (session) {
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
    } else {
      setIsLoggedIn(false);
    }

    console.log("status in context: ", status);
  }, [session]);

  return (
    <RootContext.Provider value={sessionInfo}>{children}</RootContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useSessionInfo = () => useContext(RootContext);


//SessionWrapper.tsx
"use client";

import { Session } from "next-auth";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

interface ProvidersProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  session?: Session | null;
}

export default function SessionWrapper({ children, session }: ProvidersProps) {
  return <SessionProvider session={session}>{children}</SessionProvider>;
}


//RootLayout.tsx
import "@/assets/styles/globals.css";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css";
import { config } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
config.autoAddCss = false;
import { Inter, Roboto, Raleway } from "next/font/google";
import SessionWrapper from "@/components/client/Providers/SessionWrapper";

import { auth } from "@/auth";
import { ContextWrapper } from "@/components/client/Providers/ContextWrapper";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"], display: "swap" });
const roboto = Roboto({ weight: "400", subsets: ["latin"], display: "swap" });
const raleway = Raleway({ subsets: ["latin"], display: "swap" });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Fakenews | Your SA Satire Site",
  description: "SAs most trustest source of fake news/satire",
  keywords: "satire, news, fake news, funny news",
};

const RootLayout = async ({ children }) => {
  const session = await auth();

  console.log("session in root layout: ");
  return (
    <SessionWrapper session={session}>
      <ContextWrapper>
        <html lang="en" className={`h-full ${raleway.className}`}>
          <body>{children}</body>
        </html>
      </ContextWrapper>
    </SessionWrapper>
  );
};
export default RootLayout;


//Navbar.tsx
"use client";


import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import logo from "../../img/logo_vuvuzela_transparent.png";
import ArticleSearch from "./ArticleSearch";
import { usePathname, useSearchParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";

import { useSessionInfo } from "./Providers/ContextWrapper";
import { clientLogout } from "@/app/actions/authActions";

const Navbar = ({ navLinks = [] }) => {
  const sessionInfo = useSessionInfo();
  const { session, user, isLoggedIn } = sessionInfo;  
  console.log(sessionInfo); // logs undefined, but after manual refresh logs properly

  return (//JSX);
};

export default Navbar;


I figured out the problem has something to do with how NextJS caching works. I originally used the useRouter hook's push method to programmatically route to '/' after logging in, and I suspect that when this method is used, cached data is accessed, so I reverted to using the native location.assign() method to route back to '/', which solved the problem.
